# JqPlot add click event on data points

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use jqplot http://www.jqplot.com/tests/cursor-highlighter.php.
I have successfully installed it in my framework. But i need to push a click event on the data points in the chart.

This is my code so far,

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5], ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84],
      ['26-Sep-08', 454.13], ['24-Oct-08', 379.75], ['21-Nov-08', 303], ['26-Dec-08', 308.56],
      ['23-Jan-09', 299.14], ['20-Feb-09', 346.51], ['20-Mar-09', 325.99], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Πωλήσεις από 23-May-08 μέχρι 24-Apr-09',
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d'
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '€%.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 9.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }

        });

        $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', myClickHandler]);

    });

    function myClickHandler(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {alert(1);}

</script>
```

this is my attempt to add the click event

```
$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', myClickHandler]); and

 function myClickHandler(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {alert(1);}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

lol i have found it :).
The answer was :

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5], ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84],
      ['26-Sep-08', 454.13], ['24-Oct-08', 379.75], ['21-Nov-08', 303], ['26-Dec-08', 308.56],
      ['23-Jan-09', 299.14], ['20-Feb-09', 346.51], ['20-Mar-09', 325.99], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Πωλήσεις από 23-May-08 μέχρι 24-Apr-09',
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d'
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '€%.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 9.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }
        });


        /* CLICK CODE START*/
        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {                
                alert(1);
            }
        );
        /* CLICK CODE END*/

    });

</script>
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Some more examples of jqplotDataClick can be found at http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: If you need to get a point id from database, here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827329/jqplot-click-a-point-to-remove-it-from-database/63829244#63829244